# Ensure to retain the order in a List in Java and increase efficiency

Tags: java, image

I am creating a photo mosaic in Java. The inputs to it are the Target Image and a collection of tiles. Below is my algorithm for the same:

```
a. Read all the tiles from the directory and process* it. [Every tile is of the same dimension.]
b. Read the target image, break it into cells [cells are of dimensions of a tile.]
c. Process* all the cells.
d. For each cell:
  d.1. Create a HashMap h [where key=euclidean metric, value=corresponding tile]
  d.2. For each tile:
    d.2.1 Calculate Euclidean metric.
    d.2.2 add it to h.
  d.3 Calculate min from h.
  d.4 Add the min to an outputList
e. Create the image from list of images in the outputList.
```

The *process method takes in an image and creates an object of a class we defined called `ImageDetails`. So for every tile and cell that is processed, there is an `ImageDetails` object created which stores details like its RGB value and dimensions. There are 2 separate lists of objects: one for `tiles` and other for `cells`.

The problem is that there are about on average 300 tiles and as much as 50,000 cells (can be more than that too!). So while my program runs, it has these many objects in memory, besides the calculations and other ip/op operations it performs.

When I run this program on a machine with low resources (less available memory) the output image created is distorted. But when I run it on a machine with more available resources, it is perfect. I think it is because it is not able to hold all the objects in memory at once when there are no resources available. So I see an image which has misplaced tiles. But when it has enough memory, I see perfect output image.

What can I do to ensure that regardless of the available memory, I can retain the order of the elements added in the `outputList` so that I can see an image without distortions.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Below are the 2 images that are the output of the same program. the only difference is that they are run on different machines. Please help me in understanding the difference in the output of the programs given the algorithm and the constraints.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably doesn't have anything directly to do with memory - either you have enough or you don't.

What collection class are you using for outputList? ArrayList and LinkedList should both guarantee the order of the elements.

Comment: outputList is an ArrayList. I know that it does retain the order. But what I feel is that Java reads (for example) half of the objects at once, and creates an outputList and then reads the rest and does it again when it does not have enough resource. I say that because I see the distorted image with either patches of cells wrongly placed (i.e. the patches of images that should appear in the bottom appears somewhere in the middle). I hope I am clear. I am trying to post some images so that my question becomes clear.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the problem is anywhere but in your code. This is known in the industry as the "the compiler is broken" syndrome. In short, no it's not, and neither is the ArrayList class. It's not that compiler / JVM / JVM library classes don't occasionally have bugs, but they are just about always more complex/subtle than this. If ArrayList didn't maintain it's order, a whole lot of people would know about it and complain loudly. I suggest that you break your code down into small units that you can unit test, so that you can find the problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Below are the 2 images that are the output of the same program. the only difference is that they are run on different machines. Please help me in understanding the difference in compilation of the programs given the algorithm and the constraints.

Compilation makes no difference.

Memory size *should* make no difference.  Or at least, it should not cause this kind of problem.

I suspect that what you are seeing is actually due to incorrect synchronization in a multi-threaded application.  However, without seeing your code it is unlikely we can help.  (And I suspect that your application is far too large for posting in an SO question.)

(Another theoretical possibility is that your application is "squashing" `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions.  But I can't imagine anyone doing something that stupid ...)

---

> *I have updated my question with examples.*

They are not relevant.  Please pay attention to what the Answers are saying.  It is HIGHLY UNLIKELY that the problem is in the JVM or the Java runtime libraries.  It is HIGHLY LIKELY that the problem is in your code.  Without looking at the actual code, we can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your answer. 1. I have changed the word "compilation". 2. My program is not multi-threaded. 3. I am not trying to challenge the JVM or the Libraries. I just want to understand what is happening with my code just to avoid the irregularities.